# Index of a normal core

Tags: group-theory

EDIT: Answered in the comments

#################

Let $G$ be an infinite group and suppose that $H \leq G$ is of finite index. Suppose that $\pi \colon H \to Q$ is an surjective group homomorphims such that $|Q| < \infty$.

I've seen a claim that there is a finite group $\tilde{Q}$ and a homomorphism $\tilde{\pi} \colon G \to \tilde{Q}$ such that $|\tilde{Q}| \leq |Q|^{|G:H|}$ and $\tilde{\pi} \restriction_H = \pi$.

I'm trying to prove that claim, but the best I can do is $|\tilde{Q}| \leq |G:H|\cdot|Q|^{|G:H|}$.

This is what I've done: clearly, the kernel of the map $\tilde{\pi}$ must contain the normal core of $\ker(\pi)$. If $\{g_1, \dots, g_n\} \subseteq G$, where $n = |G:H|$, is some left transversal for $H$ in $G$, then $$\text{core}_G(\ker(\pi)) = \bigcap_{i = 1}^n g_i \ker(\pi) g_i^{-1}.$$
Then I write
\begin{align*}
|\tilde{Q}| \leq |G : \text{core}_G(\ker(\pi))| &= |G:H|\cdot|H : \text{core}_G(\ker(\pi))| \\&= |G:H|\cdot|H : \cap_{i = 1}^n g_i \ker(\pi) g_i^{-1}| \leq |G:H|\cdot|Q|^{|G:H|}.
\end{align*}

Is there something I am missing or is the claim false?

Comment: I am still trying to get my head around this, but I think it is false. Let $G=A_4$, let $H = C_2 \times C_2$, and let $\pi:H \to C_2$ be any surjective homomorphism. Then there is no homomorphism $\tilde \pi$ on $G$ whose restriction to $H$ is $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt, but I am assuming that $G$ is infinite. I added that to the assumptions.

Comment: That makes no difference. Just take the direct product of everything in my example with any infinite group. The question is effectively about finite groups.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks @DerekHolt!